# Inverse of a Matrix - working but some 0's are coming out as negative (-0.)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, inverse

Trying to find the inverse of a matrix.  The below code works, the inverse comes out correctly but some of the zeros on the output are coming out as negative zero. Not sure what the issue is any help would be appreciated.  Thank you

```
# Importing NumPy Library
import numpy as np
import sys
n=3
a = np.zeros((n,2*n))
#a = np.eye(3, dtype = float)
print(a)

b = [[1, -1, 0], [0,-4,2],[0, 0, -2]]
print (b)
c = np.concatenate((b,a), axis =1)
print(c)

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        a[i][j] = b[i][j]
# Augmenting Identity Matrix of Order n
for i in range(n):        
    for j in range(n):
        if i == j:
            a[i][j+n] = 1

# Applying Guass Jordan Elimination
for i in range(n):
    if a[i][i] == 0.0:
        sys.exit('Divide by zero detected!')
        
    for j in range(n):
        if i != j:
            ratio = a[j][i]/a[i][i]

            for k in range(2*n):
                a[j][k] = a[j][k] - ratio * a[i][k]

**OUTPUT**

[[ 1.   -0.25 -0.25]
 [-0.   -0.25 -0.25]
 [-0.   -0.   -0.5 ]]
```

Comment: `-0.0` is a valid floating point value according to IEEE 754. If want to convert them to positive ones, just add `0` to the matrix.

Comment: Thank you.  I looked it up too previously and saw it was a legit zero.  Great tip to add 0 to matrix -  looks good now.  should have thought of that.  Thanks again for quick reply